# python read a given line, append line to output file then use subprocess on same line

Tags: python

I need to read a file and append row1 col1 to file before running subprocess on row1 col2 the result of which will be appended beneath initial appended line. In essence appending, processing and appending to output file before proceeding to the next line and starting again

what I have so far

```
import subprocess as sp

with open(fin) as f:
    out = open(fout, 'a') 
    while (lin := f.readline().rstrip().split()):
        out.write(lin[0] + '\n')
        cmd = ['cmd', lin[1]]
        sp.run(' '.join(cmd), shell=True, stdout=out, stderr=sp.STDOUT)
```

I am getting the result in the output but the subprocess run result is written first before all the lines I wanted to append before each subrocess run result. so what I wanted in the outfile was:

```
appended col[0] of row1
result of subprocess run on col[1] of row1
appended col[0] of row2
result of subprocess run on col[1] of row2
```

I was getting this:

```
result of subprocess run on col[1] of row1
result of subprocess run on col[1] of row2
appended col[0] of row1
appended col[0] of row2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: _Minor note:_ Looks like there might be a missing close paren here: `while (lin := f.readline().rstrip().split():`

Answer (score 2):

Add `out.flush()` after your `out.write()` call. The stuff in Python's buffer won't get flushed, because it doesn't know you're calling an external process

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I was missing. Thank you.